# How to have multiple card items in Angular Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: angular, carousel, angular-bootstrap

I am using this [carousel](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples).

I want something like the multiple-item carousel [here](http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/).

I tried following this [tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/angular-slick-carousel-slider-integration-tutorial/) but it ends up breaking my website and causes many errors.

What I have tried:

```html
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item card col-md-3" *ngFor="let image of images">
        <img src="{{image.picture}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

It does not achieve what I want. I want 2 or 3 items on the same row that you can slide through. How would you go about achieving this with Angular Bootstrap Carousel?

My last resort is paying for the [MDB](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/) library. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am now using the [PrimeNG Carousel](https://primeng.org/carousel). It does what I want.

My code:

**component.html**

```html
<div class="content-section implementation carousel-demo">
  <div class="card">
      <p-carousel [value]="images" styleClass="custom-carousel" [numVisible]="3" [numScroll]="1"
      [circular]="true" [autoplayInterval]="0" [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions">
          <ng-template let-image pTemplate="item">
            <div class="item card">
              <img src="{{image.picture}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{image.random}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
      </p-carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```js
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {
    images; 
    responsiveOptions;

    constructor() {
        this.responsiveOptions = [{
            breakpoint: '1024px',
            numVisible: 1,
            numScroll: 3
        }];
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.images = [
            {random: 'Random', picture: 'https://picsum.photos/id/944/900/500'},
            {random: 'Samoa', picture: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1011/900/500'},
            {random: 'Tonga', picture: 'https://picsum.photos/id/984/900/500'},
            {random: 'Cook Island', picture: 'https://picsum.photos/id/944/900/500'},
            {random: 'Niue', picture: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1011/900/500'},
            {random: 'American Samoa', picture: 'https://picsum.photos/id/984/900/500'}
        ];
    }
}
```

Now it's time to fetch data from firestore. Ask me if you need any help understanding. Happy coding!